# OneUI app layout, error with pulldown menus

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib, ibm-oneui

I am using the applayout and OneUI 3.0.2 theme. I have pulldown menus in the banner (application and utility links) but the menu won't show up. Instead I get this JS error:

```
Uncaught lang.hitch: scope["_onKeyPress"] is null (scope="[Widget extlib.dijit.OneUIv302Menu, extlib_dijit_OneUIv302Menu_2]")
```

I have a Windows 9.0.1FP1 where these do work. On a 9.0.1FP1 Linux / 9.0.1FP2 Windows it doesn't work. The Linux machine had FP2 installed before I just downgraded it to FP1 (it was a test to see if this is the cause). But I noticed before that even after downgrading some files are still available - so a next test should be installing the machine completely from the scratch.

Double checked it this morning: another 9.0.1FP1 Win machine - everything working fine.
I also checked out that this only a **OneUIv3.0.2** problem.

Do you know this issue?

Comment: Oliver, you have a Windows 9.0.1FP1 server where it works? and then a 9.0.1FP1 Linux where it doesn't? and then you mention a 9.0.1FP1 Windows server again? Did you mean Windows 9.0.1FP2?

Comment: Yep, it's an issue in OneUIv302 due to the dojo upgrade in FP2. I've logged it now as BGLN9PXCS3. Should be fixable in the Extension Library. Will let you know if/when it makes it into a release on OpenNTF. Thanks for reporting it

Comment: Thanks Brian. Can you give some advice how to remove the FP2 stuff from the server? The uninstaller of FP2 (downgrade to the prior version) leaves some of it on the machine so that it still loads the 1.9.2 version of Dojo.

Comment: The 1.9.2 dojo would be in the folder "<server-install>\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.dojo_9.0.1.20140801-1000". Check if that is still hanging around, and if so remove that folder. If the downgrade worked, there should be another version of that folder, with the old 1.8.3 dojo in it

Comment: Thanks, that worked partially: after removing the folder it falls back to 1.5.2 which does work with OneUI3 anymore. You have to copy the folder com.ibm.xsp.dojo_9.0.1.20131004-1200 from a clean installation (FP1) to the destination - then everything is back again!

Comment: Ok, tonight I tested a bit more. After restoring the Dojo folder from an FP1 machine (and removing the new one) I noticed another problem: the CKEditor has then issues uploading an image. The dialog is incomplete, there is no reaction with the upload button and the image is not uploaded. So I decided to re-upgrade again as I don't use OneUI3 so much on this machine but I heavily use the editor on my website.

Comment: Very strange: did clean install with FP1 on Linux and have the same issue: popup menus not showing, same error message

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this issue has been included in the latest XPages Extension Library (901v00_10.20141105-0922) on OpenNTF.

However, another issue was found in the dropdown mneu once it does appear successfully. Unfortunately a fix was not found for this secondary issue in time for the above ExtLib release. It has been logged as SPR# BGLN9PXG53.