# tree nodes in container nodes in application links doesn't link to their target xpage - in OneUI V3.0.2

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I just want to create a simple drop-down in the bannerApplicationLinks:

```
            <xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
                <xe:pageTreeNode label="Generator"
                    page="/xpGenerator.xsp" selection="/Generator/.*">
                </xe:pageTreeNode>

                <xe:basicContainerNode label="Settings">
                    <xe:this.children>
                        <xe:pageTreeNode label="manual setting"
                            page="/userprofile.xsp">
                        </xe:pageTreeNode>
                        <xe:basicLeafNode label="Language"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                    </xe:this.children>
                </xe:basicContainerNode>
                <xe:pageTreeNode label="man. setting"
                    page="/userprofile.xsp">
                </xe:pageTreeNode>
            </xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
```

the (contained) tree node "manual setting" doesn't link to "/userprofile.xsp", but to the current page.

The tree node "man. setting" links correctly to "/userprofile.xsp"

The same effect happens in the utility links. Am I missing sth?.

Server is 9.0.1, Extlib is 9.0.1

thx in advance, Uwe

Comment: I believe this is known isse SPR# BGLN9PXG53, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387258/oneui-app-layout-error-with-pulldown-menus. No fix is available for it yet

Comment: We just found out that this error/effect only occurs, when we choose OneUI V3.0.2. 
In OneUI V2.1 it works as expected.
So it looks as if this is a bug of the theme version?

Comment: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/defects/0FFE08B1FC57FE6A86257D91004C156D